# Android, Is it mandatory to work with JNI in Linux?

Tags: android, windows, linux, java-native-interface

I'm reading the book "Pro Android Games" by Vladimir Silva.
He has used Ubuntu Linux as operating system. Because I'm not expert in working with Linux, I prefer to use Windows.

My question is, can I use Windows (instead of Linux) for all of my programming and C compiling?

I installed Ubuntu on my system but it doesn't recognized my keyboard and bluetooth. It is so time consuming to handle these problems. because of these I want to stay in windows.

Thanks

Comment: Not really related but... a keyboard is actually the last piece of hardware that I would suspect  not to be recognized by Ubuntu. What kind is it ? It might be a good thing to inform some people at Ubuntu that your specific keyboard doesn't work. Even if you don't want to go the Linux way, it might help others in the same situation to find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html#tools) (emphasis mine):

> The NDK includes a set of cross-toolchains (compilers, linkers, etc..) that can generate native ARM binaries on Linux, OS X, and Windows **(with Cygwin)** platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I think so.  The Android SDK runs on Windows.  But you sound like you want to write native code.  You will need the Android native code development kit.  I don't know whether that runs on Windows or not, but I don't see why it would.